# Teams: XLS File: No longer option for printing selected area of spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-teams

Not sure what happened, but now when I choose an area of the XLS spreadsheet in Teams/Files, and choose Print, I don't have options on printing only the selected cells.  This used to work on both of my computers so I suspect Microsoft Teams updated and the functionality is no longer available.  Can anyone confirm this, or maybe something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

OK I was confused by the UI changes in the latest Teams -- the very empty screen that shows up and has options on the side.  Not sure why the UI changed because it doesn't even show the preview properly anymore either, but I found my "missing" option!

[image]